# Drobo Firewire 800 to iMac not working

Tags: mac, firewire, drobo

I have a Drobo (regular... no 'S') and I just bought a new iMac 27" with a Firewire 800 port.

I can connect my Drobo to the iMac via USB 2.0 just fine works as intended.  However, when I attempt to connect the Drobo via Firewire the Drobo is either non responsive or doesnt mount at all.  Selecting it in the Finder just makes it beachball.

Is there anything I just check?

When I go to System Profiler > Hardware > Firewire I get the following message:

```
Warning:    Unable to list FireWire devices.
Maximum Speed:  Up to 800 Mb/sec
```

I have Drobo Dashboard installed and it detects the Drobo initially then when I attempt to browse the drive Drobo Dashboard says its not detected.

Comment: Did you try Drobo support?...http://support.drobo.com/app/answers/list/kw/mac/r_id/100004/search/1

Answer (score 0):

This was most certainly the cable.  Took the cable back and got a new one... Works like a champ :)